# Cell in ag-grid not clickable using a tags

Tags: ag-grid

I have 3 columns in an ag-grid (version 23.2.0). First column and third column should be clickable to a modal.

The 3rd column has a FA pencil and works fine.

The 1st column has a name. The name is displayed but there is no clickable behavior.

[image]

I have included the code below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    
    <meta name="Components" content="">
    <meta name="Bryan Schmiedeler" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/navbar-fixed-top/">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Popper.js, -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap.js, -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ag-Grid.js, -->    
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules@23.2.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
    var columnDefs = [  
    {headerName: "Trucker Name", field: "name",cellRenderer: 'activateCellRenderer2', width:250, colSpan: function(params) {
      return params.data === 2 ? 3 : 1;
    },},
    {headerName: "Businesses", field: "model", minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 350, flex: 2,},
    {headerName: "Actions", field: "price",type:"rightAligned", cellRenderer: 'activateCellRenderer',flex: 1}
    ];
    
    // specify the data
    var rowData = [
      {name: "Ben Christy", model: "Salina", price: "A"},
      {name: "Cindy Blideman", model: "Pratt", price: "I"},
      {name: "Wes Woodson", model: "Waverly", price: "A"},
      {name: "Bryan Schmiedeler", model: "Overland Park", price: "A"}
    ];
  
    // let the grid know which columns and what data to use
    var gridOptions = {
        defaultColDef: {
            resizable: true
        },      
      columnDefs: columnDefs,
      domLayout:  'autoHeight',
      components: {
         'activateCellRenderer': ActivateCellRenderer,
         'activateCellRenderer2': ActivateCellRenderer2
      },
      rowData: rowData,
      };

    // cell renderer class
    function ActivateCellRenderer() {
    }

    // init method gets the details of the cell to be renderer
    ActivateCellRenderer.prototype.init = function(params) {       
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">\
                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"</i>\
                               </a>'
    };

    ActivateCellRenderer.prototype.getGui = function() {
        return this.eGui;
    };

    // cell renderer class
    function ActivateCellRenderer2() {
    }

    // init method gets the details of the cell to be renderer
    ActivateCellRenderer2.prototype.init = function(params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');  
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">';                    this.eGui.innerHTML += params.value;                    
        this.eGui.innerHTML += '</a>';
    };
                                    
    ActivateCellRenderer2.prototype.getGui = function() {
        return this.eGui;
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
    });   

</script>
        
  </head>

<body>
    
    <div class = "container"; style= "width: 100%";>
        <div class = "row">
           <div id="myGrid"  class="ag-theme-alpine" style="width: 100%";></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<body>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS is not happy with the way you are building innerHTML. If you do not close the tag in one line then JS will do it for you and will ignore any matching closing tag it encounters later.

do it this way and cell will render like link and will be clickable.

```
this.eGui.innerHTML = '<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">' + params.value + '</a>';
```

here is a fiddle containing your code snippet.
https://jsfiddle.net/dnfb0wop/

also check out this image explaining innerHTML fiasco.
[image: this is how innerHtml is built by browser]